# Spring Boot Test with JPA Entities

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I have a Spring Boot application (written in Kotlin) which exposes a REST endpoint through a Controller `QueueController`. I'm testing that controller in a `SpringBootTest` by calling that endpoint using `MockMvc` as follows (some boilerplate omitted for readability):

```kotlin
// QueueControllerIT.kt

@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@EnableAutoConfiguration(
    exclude = [
        JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration::class,
        DataSourceAutoConfiguration::class,
        HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration::class
    ]
)
@DirtiesContext
internal class QueueControllerIT {

    lateinit var mockmvc: MockMvc

    @Autowired
    lateinit var wac: WebApplicationContext

    @BeforeEach
    fun createStubs() {
        mockmvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build()
    }

    @Test
    fun `calling my endpoint`() {        
        mockmvc.perform(
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/stores/1/zones/one2one/customers/last")
        ).andExpect(status().isNoContent)
    }
}
```

The problem is that when calling that endpoint requests to a DB are made. The DB is modelled using JPA-Entities and CRUD-Repositories, e.g. as follows:

```kotlin
interface StoreRepository : CrudRepository<Store, Int> {
  fun findByExternalId(externalId: String): Store?
}

@Entity
class Store {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  var id: Int? = null

  @Column(name = "external_id")
  lateinit var externalId: String

  // more columns and relationships to other tables here
}
```

I am currently mocking the repositories and entities using Mockk as follows:

```kotlin
// QueueControllerIT.kt

    @MockkBean
    lateinit var storeRepositoryMock: StoreRepository

    @Test
    fun `calling my endpoint`() {   
        val store = Store()     
        every { storeRepositoryMock.findById(storeId) } returns Optional.of(store)

        mockmvc.perform(
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/stores/1/zones/one2one/customers/last")
        ).andExpect(status().isNoContent)
    }
```

However, that produces the following error:

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property externalId has not been initialized
```

Of course I could now mock/stub all the `lateinit` properties of `store` until my test succeeds, but there must be an easier way. I read a bit about `@DataJpaTest` and I think it would actually be exactly what I need, because it performs read/writes real entities to an in-memory database. However just adding `@DataJpaTest` to my test does not seem to work well with the existing setup above.
:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Configuration error: found multiple declarations of @BootstrapWith for test class [com.swisscom.oce.bouncer.controller.queue.QueueControllerIT]: [@org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(value=org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper), @org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(value=org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper)]
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I test a Spring Boot application using `@SpringBootTest` so I have a real application context and at the same time I don't have to worry about mocking/stubbing away the whole persistence layer?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can annotate the test class with `@Transactional` and the database data will be reverted after each test :)

So you won't have to mock anything repository-related.